# How do I enable hardware virtualization on ASUS M5A78l-M motherboard, AMD 8350 Processor

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, hardware-virtualization

How do I enable hardware virtualization on a ASUS M5A78l-M motherboard.

I've tried looking through the BIOS but I can't find the settings what they are usually under, and I have read that this specific motherboard should support virtualization.

I have a AMD FX(tm) 8350 Eight-Core Processor,

I would like to know where the virtualization setting should be located and how I can check if the AMD Processor supports virtualization.

Comment: In the bios look under Advanced tab>CPU configuration, enable Secure Virtual Machine Mode, save changes and exit bios.

Comment: wow, it was labeled as SVM Mode, I usually always found the setting under Northbridge settings

Comment: I read the user manual for that motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting to enable Hardware Virtualization is in BIOS, when powering on and options show push 'delete' that will bring you to the BIOS, then navigate to 'Advanced' > 'CPU Configuration', the enable "SVM Mode", 'Secure Virtual Machine Mode'. You can also look at the '[User Manuel](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A78L-M_USB3/E8017_M5A78L-M-USB3.pdf?)'.

With AMD CPU's you can check virtualization in System Info, by going to the "Run" command, entering "msinfo32" and then scrolling to the very bottom in "System Summary" witch should show if its virtualization capable.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6YYy.png)
If 'Virtualization Enabled in Firmware' says no then virtualization is just off
But if the other 'Hyper-V' options also say no then the AMD Processor doesn't support hardware virtualization